# Как работает серверный рендеринг с React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

При серверном рендеринге в React сервер отдаёт просто отрендеренный HTML или HTML c подключенными обработчиками событий и какими-нибудь данными для JS (чтобы после инициализации на сервере клиентский JS мог сразу продолжить работу)?

Т.е. если у меня, например, есть JS скрипт, который стилизует `select`, превращая `select` в набор `div` элементов с обработчиками событий выбора элемента и т.д., то если я выполню серверный рендеринг, то у меня просто готовые `div`-ы вместо `select` придут, или к ним ещё как-то будут добавлены и уже подключены события?

Просто ведь если события после серверного рендеринга не будут прикручены, то непонятно как их потом прикрутить на клиенте.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Серверный рендеринг подразумевает так же полное наличие и клиенсткого рендеринга, все что он добавляет - это исходную генерацию HTML кода на сервере, чтобы на клиенте не было эфекта пустой страницы при первоначально загрузке.

На сервере выполняется полная генерация HTML кода, 1 в 1 как на клиентской части, при этом не происходит каких либо привязок обрабочиков на события. Далее вы передаете этот HTML на клиент, и пользователь сразу видит страницу с нужным контентом. После загрузки HTML начинается выполнение JS на клиенте, и React второй!  раз (теперь на клиенте) начинает генерацию виртуального дом. После этого React сравнивает исходный DOM с тем что он сгенерировал и если изменений нет - ререндера, не происходит, и идет только привязка обработчиков событий. В обратном случае, если есть различия, то происходит полный ререндер страницы.

Comment: Т.е. получается при серверном рендеринги не получиться использовать какие нибудь сторонyие библиотеки на подобии jq ui, т.к. они не предназначены для серверного рендеринга, верно?

Comment: да, верно, для использования таких компонентов в реакт, небоходимо писать специальный реакт-компонент, который будет определять вид рендеринга - клиент или сервер, и соот-но выполнять ЖС код создания UI-компонента только на клиентском окружении